# jQuery, como alterar o z-index do datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Quando eu faço um `$('#man_dia').datepicker();` a tag com *id='man_dia'* é apenas um input, e o jQuery insere sozinho os demais elementos no DOM, eu até consigo o id que o jQuery gera para alterar via css, mas o problema é que o jQuery declara o *z-index* dentro do elemento, então mesmo eu fazendo um css assim:

```
#ui-datepicker-div { z-index: 999; }
```

Porque o stilo assume o que esta na tag, que ele gera assim:

```
<div class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" id="ui-datepicker-div" style="position: absolute; top: 132px; left: 707.7px; display: block; z-index: 1;">
```

O Que eu já tentei fazer foi assim:

```
$('#man_dia').datepicker(function(){
    $(this).css('z-index','999'); // nao resolveu
});
///////////////////////////////////////////////
$('#man_dia').datepicker(); // criar calendário primeiro
$('#man_dia').css('z-index','999'); // passar o css depois também nao resolveu
//////////////////////////////////////
$('#man_dia').datepicker();            
$('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index','999'); // passar o ID que o jQuery gera não resolveu
```

Comment: Eu uso o datepicker em uma aplicação e precisei mudar a cor de background e funcionou com "!important".
#ui-datepicker{z-index:999 !important;}

Comment: resolveu @buback eu nem sabia qual era a utilidade desse !important, se postar como resposta eu posso lhe agraciar com meu voto/aceite, obrigado desde já

Comment: Valeu, @SneepS Ninja. Que bom que funcionou! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o !important no z-index do elemento desejado. Assim ele ignora caso haja outro valor definido anteriormente.

```
#ui-datepicker { 
    z-index:999 !important; 
}
```